# why do many instances of nHibernate sample code contain Castle dlls?

Tags: nhibernate, castle

I see files like Castle.DynamicProxy.dll or Castle.Core.dll or Castle.Model.dll and various others similar in projects that are supposed to be simple, noob's introduction to nHibernate. What does this Castle stuff have to do with nHibernate? Is this unadvised muddying up the waters by the tutorial authors or does nHibernate really require this sort of extra hoops jumping just to get the basics running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NHibernate uses proxy objects to achieve lazy loading and uses the [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) module. This is the reason your entity properties need to be virtual. Because NHibernate creates proxy classes that intercept calls to your properties.

Comment: Starting with version 2.1, NHibernate has the ability to use a dynamic proxy provider other than Castle. See http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/nh2-1-0-bytecode-providers.aspx